# excel vba to autofill/sequence by 1 when the reference number in another column is the same, starting at a number based on another column

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I want to create a column (Sequential number) which adds 1 to each row where the reference in Col B remains the same. The sequence should start at the reference in Col K and add one per row. When the refernce in Col B changes the process resets the count, but still starts at the number in col k. How could i do this please?

Answer (score 0):

- Apply formula `=B2-1+COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)` to D2
- Fill down to D11

[image]

---

If you prefer to use VBA

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) - 1, 1 To 1)
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i - 1, 1) Then
            arrRes(i - 1, 1) = arrRes(i - 2, 1) + 1
        Else
            arrRes(i - 1, 1) = arrData(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arrData) - 1, 1) = arrRes
End Sub
```